# Hsql overload sum

Tags: java, hsqldb

I'm using hsql and another 3rd party library. To solve a certain problem I need to write my custom aggregate function. This page showed me how to do that: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html#src_jrt_routines

However, the other 3rd party tool restricts me to use only a predefined subset of aggregate functions. Is there any way to add an overloaded version e.g. to sum which takes a predefined type and then invokes my custom logic? I'm thinking of something very similar to the method overloading of java. Unfortunately `create aggregate function custom_sum(...)...` works, but `create aggregate function sum(...)...` doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User functions cannot override built-in functions.

You can of course disable the SUM() function by modifying the HSQLDB sources.

What is the actual problem which forces you to provide your own version of SUM()?

Comment: Thanks, at least it's good to know that what I want is impossible.

I need to overload (not override), a.k.a. extend the sum function. I need to do so because I'm using another 3rd party lib which depends on the aggregate functions on an underlying sql lib. Unfortunately this other 3rd party lib doesn't allow me to add new aggregate functions so I need to piggiback it to an existing aggregate function.